# Making a surfaceView go fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, surfaceview

I have a surface view that plays a live stream video. I need it to go fullscreen when turned landscape. I have an activity with a fragment in it that contains the surfaceView and a gridview showing other live streams. Here is the layout of the fragment -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
 >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/guiLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.6">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible">
        </SurfaceView>

    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutGrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

So my onConfigChanged in the activity calls super onConfigChanged and then calls the fragments onRotate method and passes it the newConfig  -

```
 public void onRotate(Configuration newConfig)
{
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "CHANGING");
        getView().findViewById(R.id.guiLayout).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); 
        if(gridView != null)
            gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        getView().findViewById(R.id.layoutGrid).setVisibility(View.GONE);


    }
    else
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "CHANGING PORTRAIT");

        getView().findViewById(R.id.guiLayout).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ,0.6f));

        if(gridView != null)
            gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            gridView = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gridView);


    }
```

The idea is that if I resize my guiLayout to fullscreen, its children should change to fit because they are set to MATCH_PARENT. But this is not the case, the guilayout resizes to fullscreen but the children still take up 40% of the screen as dictated by the original weight. I have tried a lot of different ways to get the children to match their parent but it has not worked. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Fullscreen:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
videoLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams videoLayoutParams = videoLayout.getLayoutParams();
videoLayoutParams.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
videoLayoutParams.height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

ViewGroup.LayoutParams videoParams = videoView.getLayoutParams();
videoParams.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
videoParams.height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. The video still plays on the same portion of the screen in landscape.

Comment: I actually did get this to work in the end, turns out the layout the fragment was sitting in needed resized as well.